# VBS timer clock - Output label

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I need some help with this code in Visual Studio VBS, I don't know how to output all the vars in the text.

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim timer
    Dim timer2
    Dim timer3
    Dim finaltimer
    timer = (sec.Text + 1)
    timer = Format(timer, "00")
    If timer = 60 Then
        timer = 0
        timer2 = (min.Text + 1)
        timer2 = Format(timer2, "00")
        If timer2 = 60 Then
            timer2 = 0
            timer3 = (hour.Text + 1)
            timer3 = Format(timer3, "00")
        End If
    End If
    finaltimer = timer & ":" & timer2 & ":" & timer3
    sec.Text = finaltimer
End Sub
```

Comment: If `sec.Text` is expected to be something like `"01:35:59"`, how do you expect to add 1 to that?

Comment: Thanks, i've seen this now...
i'm feeling a bit idiot by now

Comment: It sounds like you just want to keep track of a start time (when the "timer" started) and then do something like (I'm used to VBA, so this won't necessarily be the same in VB.Net) `finaltimer = Format(Now() - startTime, "hh:mm:ss")`

Comment: If what you want to do is display elapsed time then you should create a `Stopwatch` and `Start` it when you `Start` your `Timer`.  In the `Tick` event handler, you then get a `TimeSpan` from the `Elapsed` property of the `Stopwatch` and call its `ToString` method, passing the appropriate format specifier. That means replacing all that code with a single line.

Comment: Also, this is definitely not VBS (Visual Basic Script).  You're using VB.Net in a WinForms app.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'm just a curious trying to make a thing for my D&D sessions XD. You really did help me out

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of the StopWatch approach as suggested by jmcilhinney:

```
Private SW As New Stopwatch

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    SW.Start()
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = SW.Elapsed
    Label1.Text = ts.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
End Sub
```